# Can a curve cross its asymptote infinitely many times?

Tags: plane-curves, curves

Can a curve cross infinitely many times its asymptote?

If so, is there a special name for this behaviour?

Comment: Did you mean "Can a curve cross infinitely many times its asymptote?" ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli i mean does that still called a asymtote precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from wikipedia, this is the definition of asymptote.

In analytic geometry, an asymptote (/ˈæsɪmptoʊt/) of a curve is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as they tend to infinity

Consider the curve $ \frac{\sin x}{x} $. It's asymptote simply is $ x = 0 $, yet the asymptote does cross the curve infinitely many times.

I am not aware of a special name for this behavior.

Comment: Damped oscillation?

Comment: @bof: Damped oscillation usually refers very specifically to the type of oscillation that arises from harmonic motion plus linear damping, though it is certainly an example. The general damped oscillation follows the curve $x = A e^{-kt} \sin(ω(t+α))$ for some constants $A,k,ω,α$, where $t$ is time and $x$ is displacement from the equilibrium position.

Comment: I don't think $x=0$ is an asymptote of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.  An asymptote is arbitrarily close to the curve or tangent to it at $\infty$.  I'd like to say $\frac{1}{x}$ is an evelope of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and so $e^{-x}$ for $e^{-x} \sin kx$, etc.

Comment: @NgChungTak, it depends on your definition of asymptote. I just picked the one from wikipedia.

Comment: @AndrewAu, That's uncommon and would like to make reservation here (the diagram in Wikipedia didn't show any reference at all).  It's better to ask your professor or instructor.  Perhaps we should give another name for such thing, it's not a must to classify such thing from old stuffs.